# Is there ever going to be a sequel to "Lovelock" by Orson Scott Card?

Tags: orson-scott-card, lovelock

I once read a remarkable story called "Lovelock" about an enhanced capuchin.  It was said to be part of an upcoming "Mayflower Trilogy".  Is there a sequel planned?  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 7):

## Officially, yes, but...

Looking at [Wikipedia's article about the Mayflower trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayflower_(series)), it says that the book is planned to be called *Rasputin*. [Card's website has said, at least since 2010, that the book is in progress](http://www.hatrack.com/osc/bibliography/index.shtml). However, in 2015 the co-author of the first book died. As far as I have found, he has not said what's going on with the book since.

In 2010, he said this:

> Lovelock, on the other hand, is waiting for me to solve some story problems.  I know the next volume focuses on the cat assassin Rasputin, and that he comes head-to-head with his assigned target, Lovelock. Beyond that, there's a lot to discover!  Not ready to write it yet. To Kathy Kidd's great chagrin.
>
> <sub>[source](https://live.washingtonpost.com/orson-scott-card.html)</sub>

I am betting that this is not ever going to happen, but we'll see.